# How to use a CMS page as front page for PrestaShop and have the default shop index to /someurl?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've made this custom IndexController.php into  /override/controllers/front to have a CMS page as index (see `$id_cms`).

```
class IndexControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    //public $php_self = 'index';

    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    /*public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'index.js');

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array('HOOK_HOME' => Hook::exec('displayHome'),
            'HOOK_HOME_TAB' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTab'),
            'HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTabContent')
        ));
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'index.tpl');
    }*/

    public $php_self = 'cms';
    public $assignCase;
    public $cms;

    /** @var CMSCategory */
    public $cms_category;
    public $ssl = false;

    public function canonicalRedirection($canonicalURL = '')
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('live_edit')) {
            return;
        }
        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($this->cms) && ($canonicalURL = $this->context->link->getCMSLink($this->cms, $this->cms->link_rewrite, $this->ssl))) {
            parent::canonicalRedirection($canonicalURL);
        } elseif (Validate::isLoadedObject($this->cms_category) && ($canonicalURL = $this->context->link->getCMSCategoryLink($this->cms_category))) {
            parent::canonicalRedirection($canonicalURL);
        }
    }

    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();

        if ($this->assignCase == 1) {
            $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'cms.js');
        }

        $this->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'cms.css');
    }

    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        $id_cms = 6;
        $this->cms = new CMS($id_cms, $this->context->language->id);

        $parent_cat = new CMSCategory(1, $this->context->language->id);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('id_current_lang', $this->context->language->id);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('home_title', $parent_cat->name);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('cgv_id', Configuration::get('PS_CONDITIONS_CMS_ID'));

        if (isset($this->cms->id_cms_category) && $this->cms->id_cms_category) {
            $path = Tools::getFullPath($this->cms->id_cms_category, $this->cms->meta_title, 'CMS');
        } elseif (isset($this->cms_category->meta_title)) {
            $path = Tools::getFullPath(1, $this->cms_category->meta_title, 'CMS');
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'cms' => $this->cms,
            'content_only' => (int)Tools::getValue('content_only'),
            'path' => $path,
            'body_classes' => array($this->php_self.'-'.$this->cms->id, $this->php_self.'-'.$this->cms->link_rewrite)
        ));

        if ($this->cms->indexation == 0) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('nobots', true);
        }

        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms.tpl');
    }
```

Now my question is: how can I have the original shop index rendered to a url like /store?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a custom controller in /controllers/front

```
class myStoreIndexController extends FrontController {

  public $php_self = 'myStoreIndex';

  /**
   * Assign template vars related to page content
   * @see FrontController::initContent()
   */
  public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'index.js');
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
      'HOOK_HOME' => Hook::exec('displayHome'),
      'HOOK_HOME_TAB' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTab'),
      'HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTabContent')
    ));
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'index.tpl');
  }
}
```

2) Go into PS control panel menu: Settings > SEO & Urls, click "Add new page" then select as Page our "myStoreIndexController", set the title and meta you need and finally enter "store" as friendly url and save

[image]

3) Enjoy a cms homepage + store in your custom path

Comment: That's what I was talking about when I said "I would have create a new cms page or a new custom controller." ;). Did you redirect the base `www.yoursite.com/` to `/store` in `.htaccess`?

Comment: yeah, I've finished doing it before reading your answer :) I wrote here because I haven't found a clear solution on PS forums. No, I don't want to redirect the root as I have my cms page as root. I'm still testing if this solution works as expected without breaking some functionality or if more work is needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to mess with the internal Prestashop Dispatcher to declare a base url for index. I just had a quick look at core classes and can't figure out how to handle this easily.

If I had to do this, I would have create a new cms page or a new custom controller. And simply redirect in `.htaccess` the root to this page:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /store [L,R=301]

# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically
# [...]
```

Comment: I will answer myselft with the solution I've just implemented: custom controller + settings > seo and urls